# how to properly initialize a new class and pass a value to use for it's methods

Tags: php

Say I have the following class:

```
class Item{
    public $itemid;
    public $itemattribute;

    function __construct($itemid){
        $this->itemid = $itemid;
    }
    public function getData(){
        $this->itemattribute = foo($itemid);
    }
}
```

Then I'm initiating a new object with this code:

```
$item = New Item($itemid);
$item->getData();
var_dump($item);
```

Basically what I am trying to do, is define the `$itemid` when I initialize the object, and when I call `$item->getData`, have it perform that function, using the previously defined `$itemid`. This is my first class and attempt writing OOP from scratch, so bear with me. The problem is that the `$itemid` isnt being passed to the `foo` function within `getData`.

Comment: Sorry, I edited it for clarification.

Comment: Why does getData is not returning anything, the name is getData the name implies that we are supposed to get some data out of it. Also in OOP the attributes are private not public eg: public $itemid; should be private $itemid; in any method into the class Item the value of private $itemid; can be access via $this->itemid;

Comment: Its not private because I will need to output that from the object later on in the script. getData doesn't return anything, it simply populates the needed variables with data that I will then access from the object.

Comment: In proper OOP the access to attributes must be through methods. That is called encapsulation (See here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(object-oriented_programming)). Public attributes is bad OOP, only methods should be public, the most access an attribute can get is protected, and that is only in specific cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach seems right (Except you need to use $this-> to access the property), but: Do yourself a flavour and have a look at how getter and setter are normaly used. A getter should return something, while a setter sets something. If you need to do "something" internal, you should use another method, or even do it in the constructor, etc..

```
class Item{
    public $itemid;
    public $itemattribute;

    function __construct($itemid){
        $this->itemid = $itemid;
    }

    public function getItemId(){
        return $this->itemid;
    }

    //option 1:) 
    public function calculateAttributeValue(){
       $this->itemAttribute = foo($this->itemid);
    }

    //option 2:)
    public function calculateAttributeValue($func){
       $this->itemAttribute = $func($this->itemid);
    }

    //option 3:) (lazy loading)
    public function getItemAttribute(){
       if ($this->itemAttribute == null){
           $this->itemAttribute = foo($this->itemid);
       }

       return $this->itemAttribute;
    }

    //option 4 (eager loading)
    function __construct($itemid){
        $this->itemid = $itemid;
        $this->itemAttribute = foo($this->itemid);
    }

    public function getItemAttribute(){
       return $this->itemAttribute;
    }
}
```

However it is a GOOD idea, to either use eager OR Lazy loading. Whenever you need to "call" another function in order to compute a value, BEFORE a getter will return a value, your design becomes sensitive to "calling the functions in the right order", which will be bad for large Classes, and even worse, if one calculation depends on another calculation done prior...

Bad usagE:

```
$myClass = new Item(5);
$myClass->CalulateA();
$myClass->CalculateB();
$myClass->getB();
```

Better:

```
$myClass = new Item(5); //calculates A and B
$myClass->getB();
```

or

```
$myClass = new Item(5);
$myClass->getA(); //calculates A.
$myClass->getB(); //calculates B and A when required.
```

Comment: Very good and valuable input. I was wondering about performing all my populating functions when I initiated the class (eager loading i suppose).

Answer (score 2):

to call the itemid in your function simply load it inside the function.

```
class Item{
 public $itemid;
 public $itemattribute;

 function __construct($itemid){
    $this->itemid = $itemid;
 }
 public function getData(){
    $itemid = $this->itemid; // or 
    // simply. do  what ever you want to itemid
    $this->itemid;

   return  $this->itemattribute = foo('bar');
   // you should have return

 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pull the value with `$this->itemid` and not `$itemid` in your `getData` function in order to "pass" the value to the function:

```
class Item{
    public $itemid;
    public $itemattribute;

    function __construct($itemid){
        $this->itemid = $itemid;
    }
    public function getData(){
        // echo $this->itemid; // This will print the same value you passed to the constructor
        $this->itemattribute = foo( $this->itemid); // <-- HERE
    }
}
```

Note that if you expect a value from `getData()`, you'll need to return something:

```
public function getData(){
    $this->itemattribute = foo( $this->itemid);
    return $this->itemattribute;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After you create the object:

```
$item = New Item($itemid);
```

`$item->itemid` takes the value of `$itemid` according to your constructor.

So just use `$item->itemid` in your `getData()` method

Answer (score -1):

```
public function getData(){
    return $this->item_id;
}
```

That will return the item id of the class

Comment: ant the relation to the question is... ?

Comment: It had full relation to the question previous to the edit as the OP was asking how the getData() function would have access to the item_id variable.

Comment: I am suprised you got a vote down as you were the only one who returned the data as indicated.  Voted you back up.

Comment: @karmafunk - 1) OP doesn't need (or want) to return the data, it's a public variable. 2) The variable name is `$itemid` not `$item_id`. 3) There is no explanation or context to the original question, since the OP wants to call the function `foo()` with the value of the member variable. Hence the downvotes.

Comment: His original question stated he wanted to return the value!  You guys with your egos! Tut tut.

Comment: @nickb he asked originally for the value to be returned, he also didn't state previously that he wanted to call the function `foo()` with the itemid (No underscore in the variable, obviously) just how that function could access the class variable.